# How to handle empty sequence with theano.scan()?

Tags: python, theano

The code snippet is like:

```
t = tensor.arange(1, K)
results, updates = theano.scan(fn=updatefunc, sequences=t, ...)
```

the scan process will iterate along t. However, when K<=1, t will be an empty range, then theano.scan() will crash. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `theano.ifelse.ifelse` to compute the scan only when the sequence has some elements in it. For example:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt
import theano.ifelse


def step(x_t, s_tm1):
    return s_tm1 + x_t


def compile():
    K = tt.lscalar()
    t = tt.arange(1, K)
    zero = tt.constant(0, dtype='int64')
    outputs, _ = theano.scan(step, sequences=[t], outputs_info=[zero])
    output = theano.ifelse.ifelse(tt.gt(K, 1), outputs[-1], zero)
    return theano.function([K], outputs=[output])


def main():
    f = compile()
    print f(3)
    print f(2)
    print f(1)
    print f(0)
    print f(-1)


main()
```

prints

```
[array(3L, dtype=int64)]
[array(1L, dtype=int64)]
[array(0L, dtype=int64)]
[array(0L, dtype=int64)]
[array(0L, dtype=int64)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I've never thought part of computation graph can stay still. Really learned things from you.

Comment: I encountered a new problem: if ifelse is changed to tensor.switch, the scan still will be evoked even when K<=1, then it will crash.

Comment: I think I find the answer here: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/conditions.html. It says "switch evaluates both output variables, ifelse is lazy and only evaluates one variable with respect to the condition". The reason I changed ifelse to switch is because ifelse is implemented in python not in C, so it's much slower than switch.

Comment: Much slower? Have you measure it?

Comment: Yes, in my code, if I change all 'ifelse' to 'switch', it runs ~2 times faster. It's said 'switch' is implemented in C, but 'ifelse' is not.